# Where are we with potential 5e promotions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It seems like we're stalled out here with any potential 5e promotion.

Where are we, what's going on behind the scenes?

What can we as a community do to help?

With the first release slated for Thursday during US West Coast Business hours, it would be helpful to know what our schedule looks like.

Comment: Time is running out :-)

Answer (score 6):

Users have been selected to get the books from the Nominations thread and have been emailed for their physical addresses by Grace Note/the SE team.

Comment: Rad, thanks for letting us know. I think the topic is, broadly, also about the status on stuff like [this](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3664/1204), or [this](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3608/1204), both regarding [this original answer](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3580/1204) from Grace Note. Theoretically we'll have some kind of promotional site design?

Comment: Yeah that's more of what I'm looking for. The stuff is great, but this is a big opportunity and it looks like we're largely letting it pass instead of taking it.

Comment: I can't speak for @GraceNote and them - we propose but we aren't really involved much after that - sometimes they show back up with something, sometimes they don't.